# Closing channels in Go

Tags: go, channel

I am learning how channels work in Go and have stumbled upon a problem with closing the channels. This is a modified example from *A Tour of Go*, which generates n-1 fibonacci numbers and sends them through the channels, leaving the last "element" of the channel capacity unused.

```
func fibonacci(n int, c chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for i := 0; i < n-1; i++ {
        c <- x
        x, y = y, x+y

    }
    // close(c) // It's commented out on purpose
}

func main() {
    n := 10
    c := make(chan int, n)
    go fibonacci(n, c)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        _, ok := <-c
        fmt.Println(ok)
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get:

> fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

when I do not close the channel. What exactly is causing the deadlock? Why  can't I receive from the channel in its capacity boundaries when I don't close it?

Comment: FYI, if you are expecting to close a channel, the idomatic way of reading a channel is `for v := range c {` as you don't need to check OK - the for loop will exit when the channel is closed. and if u don't expect a channel to close, use a `for { select { case v := <- c: ... `. that way you can have additional `case` conditions such as timeouts, monitoring cancel tokens, etc and break out the for loop when an exit condition is detected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're writing *n* values into the channel (from 0 to *n-1*), but are trying to read *n+1* values from the channel (from 0 to *n*).  Without explicitly closing the channel, the `main` function will wait forever for this last value.

> What exactly is causing the deadlock?

After *n* iterations, the goroutine running the `fibonacci` function will exit. After this goroutine has exited, the only remaining goroutine in your program is the `main` goroutine, and this goroutine is waiting for some data to be written to the `c` channel -- and since there is no other goroutine left that might ever write data into this channel, it will wait forever. This is exactly what the error message is trying to tell you: *"all goroutines* ("all" is just "one", here) *are asleep"*.

The `_, ok := <- c` call in the `main` function will only stop blocking as soon as the `c` channel is closed (as reading from a channel is blocking, this needs to be done from another goroutine). When the channel is closed, the `main` function will read remaining data from the channel (when it's a buffered channel)

Answer (score 0):

For loop in main expect n communication in channel, but you produce only n-1 in func fibonacci

```
func fibonacci(n int, c chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ { //here
        c <- x
        x, y = y, x+y

    }
    // close(c) // It's commented out on purpose
}
```

should work
http://play.golang.org/p/zdRuy14f9x

Comment: I know, that's also on purpose, to leave one "element" of channel's capacity empty.

Comment: But it cause a deadlock. In main you wait for n's message in channel forever because you don't send it.